# inconsistent blocking behaviour of window.prompt on mobile device

Tags: javascript, mobile, alert, prompt

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = prompt("enter x");
    var y = prompt("enter y");
    alert(x + " " + y);
</script>
```

This very simple code prompts the user for `x`, then for `y` and then displays an alert with both values. On desktop browsers this works fine because `window.prompt` and `window.alert` are blocking.

When viewing via a mobile device (user agent at the end of this post) the first prompt blocks but when I hit "OK" the second prompt is not blocking so the alert pops imediatelly with the following message (assume I entered `5` on the first prompt):

```
5 null
```

Why does this happen? Can it be solved?

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/YEA5w/

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.5; en-gr; HTC_WildfireS_A510e
>   Build/GRJ90) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile
>   Safari/533.1

Comment: You could try not to use blocking `prompt`/`alert` functions at all but replace them with `<input>`s :-)

Answer (score 0):

For the record, on my Samsung Galaxy S2 both on the stock and Firefox browsers, your fiddle works fine for me.

If you are still having issues, perhaps you could use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to continuously check if these prompts have been filled in and do the alert if they have.

Something like:

```
<script>
    var x = false;
    var y = false;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
            if(x !== false && y !== false) {
                 alert(x + " " + y);
                 clearInterval(timer);
            }
    },100);
    x = prompt("enter x");
    y = prompt("enter y");
</script>
```